# how to get and set the size of a window in pixels

Tags: c#, windows

I have a Window in C# (System.Windows.Window).
I've looked into the documentation and for some reason, the window's width and height are not measured in Pixels but in (1/96)Inch.
is there Any way to set and get a window's size in Pixels instead of the aforementioned unit?

I've found ways of getting the size of the current working area in pixels (which is not necessarily my window) but not of setting it.

additional info:
OS: windows.

Comment: [DPI and Device-Independent Pixels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels).

Comment: What functions or properties are you using to get/set the Width and Height of this Window? Does it belong to your own app? If it's your app, what values return `this.ActualWidth` and `this.Width`?

Comment: @Jimi I'm using the standard width and height currently, this is my app, ActualWidth and Width return doubles representing the size in 1/96inch, width= desired width, ActualWidth = the windows actual width, not sure why these values are different values

Comment: @IInspectable how do I get those values in C#?

Comment: Isn't that what you need to know? If you design at 96 Dpi, your FrameworkElement has a measure. If the Dpi scale changes... -- What IInspectable posted applies to any UI Framework. You have to make the same considerations in Win32 and WinForms, for example. When you measure graphics elements, the current Dpi setting needs to be considered. The difference is that some Frameworks requires more *manual* intervention that others.

Comment: @Jimi I have looked into it and edited my comment, I'm now asking how to get dpi in C#

Comment: [VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getdpi)

Comment: You can also use `var source = PresentationSource.FromVisual([Element]); var dpiX = 96.0 * source.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;` and `M12` for the `Y` value. You might get more *insight* if you explain what do you need these measure for.

Comment: @Jimi thank you, that solved the problem